# How to set height of UITableView programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a Table View and I want to set the height of the table view through code programatically. How do I do it?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried by setting frame of table

Comment: shoudl really be using autolayout at this point, so you may want to search, add constraints to UITableview programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in **ViewDidAppear**:

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: desiredHeight)
```

Comment: This will not compile in Swift 3.

Comment: Updated the answer bro. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Make outlet of UITableView

[image: Create IBOutlet of UITableView]

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

Step 2:Now set Frame of tableView in **ViewDidLoad()** method.

> viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
  tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: yourwidth, height: yourheight)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a Swift 3.1 version:

```
//Create table view
let tableView = UITableView();
//Set frame
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height:100);
//Add the table to a view as a subview
superView.addSubview(tableView); 
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

Sivajee Battina answer techanically is correct, however, you should not use CGRectMake when using Swift 3. Here is a Swift 3 answer:

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myWidth, height: myHeight)
```